# Git checkout removed file but no changes?

Tags: git

I had some problems with git and it couldnt save some changes properly and it made 2 copies. I deleted the copies then I used the command `git checkout -- fileName` and now the file is present and I can see it with my IDE but it is empty.

The trick is - I havent made a commit. So..on the server the file is up and ready but on my local machine its not. When I try to copy and paste the code from the server into my local file I get an error "No such file or directory exists" even though its visible in my IDE it cant save the changes (PHPStorm).

Here is the console what I actually did

```
➜  myProject(myBranch) ✗ git status
On branch myBranch
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   assets/src/js/header.js

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    assets/src/js/header.js___jb_old___
    assets/src/js/header.js___jb_tmp___

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
➜  myProject git:(myBranch) ✗ rm assets/src/js/header.js___jb_old___ 
➜  myProject git:(myBranch) ✗ git status
On branch myBranch
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   assets/src/js/header.js

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    assets/src/js/header.js___jb_tmp___

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
➜  myProject git:(myBranch) ✗ rm assets/src/js/header.js___jb_tmp___ 
➜  MyProject git:(myBranch) ✗ git status
On branch myBranch
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   assets/src/js/header.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
➜  myProject git:(myBranch) ✗ git diff assets/src/js/header.js        
➜  myProject git:(myBranch) ✗ git checkout -- assets/src/js/header.js 
➜  myProject git:(myBranch) git status
On branch myBranch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

As you can see I had a file with two copies made by git. Then I removed the copies and used git checkout to try and revert all changes.

Currently the file is empty even though again I havent made any commits. I havent commited anything

I just want my file to come as it was and as it is currently on the server.

***[EDIT]*** - I tried `git reset HEAD assets/src/js/header.js` but nothing happened. I know the file is on the server but I cant make my local copy to be the same as on the server.

***[EDIT]*** - I also tried switching between different branches and the file is still empty and there are no changes for commit.

Comment: I think this comment: "When I try to copy and paste the code from the server into my local file I get an error "No such file or directory exists" even though its visible in my IDE it cant save the changes (PHPStorm).", is suggesting that there's something more weird going on that it seems. Can you confirm (using a simple text editor, not an IDE) that the file definitely exists? For example, what happens if you do `cat assets/src/js/header.js`?

Comment: Oh, and what does `git diff` show you has changed?